# The new Appcelerator Titanium Facebook API: How do we perform a simple connect?

Tags: facebook, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to use the new Facebook Graph API with Appcelerator Titanium Mobile 1.6 .
I found two complete examples on the net:
[That one](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/02/facebook-module-changes-in-titanium-mobile-1-6-0.html) from the official blog et the [Aaron's one](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/3515094865/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-facebook-oauth-in-1-6-0).

In both examples, I wonder where should put the `app_id` and the `app_secret`? Where the login action is performed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't try it, but have a look at the api Ti.[Facebook](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module) and the [dev.facebook-help](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). maybe it will help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's loads of examples on the [documentation page](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module.html) for the module - the app_id should go in tiapp.xml and then is also set within your code, as stated on that page (see the authorize example). I don't think secret is used anymore in the new Facebook module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register you application in http://developers.facebook.com -> Apps -> Create new app

After that you will see app id and app secret.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium.Facebook.appid = "your app id";

put above line in app.js file

```
   <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
   <module platform="android">facebook</module>
```

put this live in tiapp.xml

first you have to require facebook.